# section is smaller than contents

Tags: html, css

The default layout page I get in a MVC razor has a problem with the section tag being smaller than its contents.  The issue is I have a large table inside of it, and it is running out of the section, rather than the section simply becoming wide enough to fit it.  I have recreated the issue in jsFiddle.  You can see that the blue box is much thinner than the red box.  The blue section being the initial size of the window, but if you scroll right, then you see the table is wider than the section.

**How do I get the section to widen to match the size of its contents?**

```
<div class="page">        
    <section id="main" style="background:blue;height:50px">
       <table style="width:1000px; overflow:auto;background:red">
           <tr><td>lkjlkjlkjlkjjhgjhgjhgjgjhgjhg</td></tr>

        </table>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sDG8n/1/

Answer (score 1):

Float the section to the left

```
<section id="main" style="float:left;background:blue;height:50px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `overflow:auto` on the section instead of on the table.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-section-element) says you're doing it wrong:

> The section element represents a generic document or application
>   section…The section element is not a generic container element. When
>   an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead

In other words: Use a `DIV`.

Comment: "you're doing it wrong" You're reading it wrong.  I stated clearly this is not a design decision I made, but comes by default with the MVC project.  I am reluctant to change this without understanding what hooks/conventions might depend on it being there.